# Issue with search bar in iOS 11 have large titles

Tags: uisearchbar, ios11, large-title

I have enabled large titles and have applied color on navigation bar.
Now when i am scrolling, it is showing a white bar above searchbar.

Here is the [Sample](https://i.imgur.com/ZrEOcjM.gif).  Also i am facing this issue on Real device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Translucent on navigation bar
Or put this code

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: But i want navigation bar Translucent

Comment: @LibraTaimur set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true ??

Comment: how? @LibraTaimur

Comment: I have tried setting extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true. Still no luck.